# Automatic access to index counter inside Python loop over iterator

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, iterator

I need to loop over an iterable and also have access to an index counter inside that loop:

```
i = 0
for item in items:
  # ...
  i += 1
```

Is there more consices Python syntax for doing that, perhaps one that both progresses the iterator and increases the index counter in the same `for` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python has an [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function:

```
items = 'abcdef'

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    print(i, item)
```

which prints:

```
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
5 f
```